# Stuck proxy settings in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, proxy

I set proxy settings back when I was connected to the office via VPN, but they got stuck somehow and I cannot remove them.

What I checked and tried:

- `~/.bashrc` - nothing here
- `/etc/environment` - nothing here
- Settings > Network > Network Proxy - set to `Disabled`
- Multiple restarts or relogs in between changes to the settings.

Still, whenever I log in I have proxy settings active. It's messing up with vscode as it's always accessing the extension marketplace via proxy and failing.

Any ideas what else I can try?

Comment: Yeah. I usually check it with `env | grep proxy` and it's always there. I can get rid of it by adding unset commands to `~/.bashrc` but I don't think it removes it for all other programs too.

Comment: It's not in either of them nor `/etc/profile` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: That's it! I had a bash script in `/etc/profile.d/*`. I forgot I put it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are always more places to hide default environment variables.

If the environment is set for a single user, it is worthwhile looking at these locations (assuming a bash shell):

- .bashrc
- .bash_profile
- .bash_aliases (I know it shouldn't but it is sourced)
- .profile
- .login

if this is affecting all users, it's also worthwhile looking at these locations:

- /etc/profile
- /etc/profile.d/*
- /etc/environment
- /etc/profile
- /etc/bash_completion (again, it shouldn't be, but this is generally sourced from a users .bashrc)

glad you found the location.

Comment: Even though there are many similar answers all over the place, I have never seen `/etc/profile.d/*` being mentioned. Not even sure how and why I added my script there.
Hopefully, this will serve for the future searchers as a summarized post.